# Latest version of Git in Bash?

Tags: git, bash, shell, installation

Trying to the pull the latest version of Git from http://git-scm.com but the script below doesn't seem to be printing out anything...

What am I missing here?

```
if [ -z "$CURRENT_GIT_VERSION" ]; then
    if [ "`uname`" == "Darwin" ]; then 
        sed_regexp="-E"; 
    else 
        sed_regexp="-r"; 
    fi
    CURRENT_GIT_VERSION=$(curl http://git-scm.com/ 2>&1 | grep '<span class="version">' -A 1 | tail -n 1 | sed $sed_regexp 's/ *//')
fi
echo "$CURRENT_GIT_VERSION"
```

Not working:

```
CURRENT_GIT_VERSION=$(curl -silent http://git-scm.com/ | sed -n '/id="ver"/ s/.*v\([0-9].*\)<.*/\1/p')
echo "$CURRENT_GIT_VERSION"
```

Also not working:

```
CURRENT_GIT_VERSION=$(echo $(curl -s http://git-scm.com/ | grep 'class="version"' -A 2) | perl -pe 's/.*?([0-9\.]+).*/$1/')
echo "$CURRENT_GIT_VERSION"
```

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that `http://git-scm.com/` is redirecting to `https://git-scm.com/`, and `curl` doesn't follow redirects by default.

Try fetching from `https://git-scm.com/` directly.

Alternatively, add a `-L` option to the `curl` command to get it to follow redirects.